# Code runs on localhost not on app server

Tags: java, angularjs, excel

I am developing a code for xcel generation and download using apache poi. LocalHost server and app server is jboss. When i run the code on localhost, a temp folder is generated in jboss's deployment folder and in that the xcel is generated and then downloaded through frontend. I am using java spring angularjs and html. This runs fine on localhost but after deploying on app server the xcel is not downloaded and it gives 500:internal server error.

angularjs controller code:

```
$scope.generateExcel=function(sDate,eDate,doc,search)
{
    console.log("hello");

    var sDate = document.getElementById('sD').value
    var eDate = document.getElementById('eD').value

    $scope.obj.sDate = sDate;
    $scope.obj.eDate = eDate;
    $scope.obj.iou = doc;
    $scope.obj.du = search; 
    console.log($scope.obj);


    $http.post('abc/generateExcel',$scope.obj).then(function() 
            {
                //console.log(path);
                $window.location.href="/ProjectName/file_name.xls";
            })
    .error(function()
    {
        console.log("Error!!");
    });
};
```

java code:
//Method

```
public HttpServletResponse generateExcel ( HttpServletRequest request , HttpServletResponse response, String sD, String eD, String doc, String search)
 {
    //EXCEL GENERATION HERE

  response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
  response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=filename.xls");
       //Path Specification
                String path = request.getRealPath("/file_name.xls");
                //System.out.println("Here...");
                System.out.println(path);
                FileOutputStream fileOut2 = new FileOutputStream(path);

                workbook.write(fileOut2);

            /*returning response*/
}
```

Comment: `"500:internal server error."` mean something go wrong on server. Look into server logs.

Comment: pass the error into your onerror like so... `.error(function(e){console.log(e);});`

Comment: Nothing in server logs and Also the temp folder of ProjectName and file is not generating in app server's jboss. All the permissions are granted to the jboss folder on server. @talex

Comment: Nothing at all?You method is logging something in `System.out.println(path);` did you found output? Are you sure you method being invoked?

Comment: The method runs fine..On localhost this path gives //D:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments\ProjectName.war\file_name.xls.. @talex

Comment: The fact that it is runs fine on localhost do not lead to conclusion that it is run fine in other environment.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer this unless one knows what's the error you are getting on the server side. Put your server code in a try-catch block. Rerun the code, and check the server logs. Paste them here.

```
try{
     String path = request.getRealPath("/file_name.xls");
            //System.out.println("Here...");
            System.out.println(path);
            FileOutputStream fileOut2 = new FileOutputStream(path);

            workbook.write(fileOut2);
  } catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace(); // this should print some error in server logs
  }
```